# localization and registration ios app

Tags: ios, localization, registration

We're working on app which will deliver content to users from different countries (Europe).And I have a problem-we can register only 10 000 items in IAP.
What can you suggest: the content will be different for every country,and have I to make, for example, 5 app, but for every country, or use localization?

And can I register my app in Germany if I live in Russia?

Thank you.

Comment: IAP stands for in app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When publishing an App through iTunes, you are free to select any country (or a combination of countries) that App should be available for.

See this (hopefully up-to-date) list of countries Apple is servicing with their localized versions of the AppStore (headlined: Internationalization): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes_Store.

Comment: ok. thank you. but if I'd like to register app for different countries -it will be several different app with a combination of content-what's about NAME of app? will it be the same? of with some remark?

Comment: Yes, you may have localized App names.